# CastCompanionLibrary - orientation changed when loading

Tags: android, google-cast

I am using CastCompanionLibrary in my application for playing movies via GoogleCast. 
I start `VideoCastControllerActivity` with this line of code:

```
mVideoCastManager.startVideoCastControllerActivity(mActivity, mediaInfo, startPosition, autoPlay, activeTracks);
```

After calling this method, VideoCastControllerActivity is started and movie is loading. There is a ProgressBar in the middle of the activity, and views for controlling of playback (SeekBar, Play/Pause button, ...) are not visible, which is fine. When loading of movie is finished, ProgressBar disappears and Play/Pause button, SeekBar, etc are visible now. It is fine.

But there is a one little issue. When I change the orientation when movie is loading, then ProgressBar are still visible, because movie is still loading, but Play/Pause button, Seekbar, etc are now visible too - it is undesirable behavior, because the movie is still loading.

I tried to fix this. This is my modified code in `VideoCastControllerFragment`:

```
public void onConfigurationChanged() {
    updateOverallState();
    if (mSelectedMedia == null) {
        if (mMediaAuthService != null) {
                showImage(Utils.getImageUri(mMediaAuthService.getMediaInfo(), 1));
        }
    } else {
        updateMetadata();
        updatePlayerStatus();
        int playbackStatus = mCastManager.getPlaybackStatus();
        boolean canShowUiControllers = canShowUiControllers(playbackStatus);
        mCastController.updateControllersStatus(mCastManager.isConnected() && canShowUiControllers);
    }
}

// My method
private boolean canShowUiControllers(int playbackStatus) {
    return playbackStatus == MediaStatus.PLAYER_STATE_PLAYING || playbackStatus == MediaStatus.PLAYER_STATE_PAUSED;
}
```

I have no success with this modification.

Could you help me, please, how can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please open a bug on the CCL's issue tracker on GitHub? I should be able to get to it soon...

Comment: @AliNaddaf I created issue here: https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android/issues/197